# fetch data from db using javascript & php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This js var has the country

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var siteCmd_Country="<?php echo siteCmd_Country_P ;?>";  
</script>

function getCountryRedirectUrl() {

        var  url_res = '#';
        if(geoCountryName != '' && geoCountryName != null){

            if(geoCountryName =='United Kingdom'){
                //  window.location=Url+'uktutorsdirectory.co.uk';
                url_res = Url+'UK';//Url+'uk';
            }else if(geoCountryName =='United States'){
                url_res = Url+'usa';
            }else if(geoCountryName =='Canada'){
                url_res = Url+'canada';
            }else if(geoCountryName =='India'){
                url_res = Url+'india';
            }else if(geoCountryName =='Italy'){
                url_res = Url+'italy';
            }else if(geoCountryName =='Ireland'){
                url_res = Url+'ireland';
            }else if(geoCountryName =='Malaysia'){
                url_res = Url+'malaysia';
            }
        }
        return url_res;
}
```

this function gives the changes the url based on the geoCountryName(It is basically the country frm whr the site has been accessed)
What i want is the above method is hardcoded for every country. Now i have created an entry in db which maps country with its aliases. so i pass the geoCountryName to the query and get the aliases and append the url with alias.

url_res = Url+"countryAlias"; which is in JS funct and alias comes frm php-mysql

I tried using php but it is not working fine.below is the code

```
    $conn = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, DBUSER, DBPWD);
    mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $conn);
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
    $sWhere = "CountryName=".siteCmd_Country_P;
    $sql = "SELECT CountryAlias FROM `t_countrycharges`  "
            . "$sWhere ";

    $pacrs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($pacrs);
    $row = @mysql_fetch_object($pacrs))
    $CountryAlias = $row->CountryAlias;
```

Actually the page in which all these code contains is the php page so i need to add all the code in the same page. now when i run the page with these code then the half page doesn't load and it is not showing any output. Please help me with these asap.I need to run the php on same page but there is no action or click event which can be controlled so please assist on it. All help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me. So the problem lies purely in your php script? Because I do see some flaws in that. I'm not sure if you need help with combining the JS + the PHP side, or only the php side?

Comment: actually i want to retrieve a value from database to javascript. siteCmd_Country(JS var) / $siteCmd_Country_P(php var)  variable which contains the country name. i want the alias matching to that country from db  in js funct.

Comment: I want it in js so i can use php + js approach also which ever is fine.. and works for me. and in the same .php file

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax to communicate from frontend to backend.

this might be helpful http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Yes Garry i can use that but i have php code in same file and there is no event which can  generate the call.

Comment: You can still use ajax without having an event. if purpose for checking, you can call the ajax when the page is loaded, you need the ajax to connect between your front end and backend, javascript can't connect to the database.

Comment: Ok Garry it worked fine with ajax..thanks for the approach

Answer (score 0):

I'll just paste an example of a project I'm working on here. I think it could help you understand. I assume you're OK with `jQuery` since you have it as a tag.

To start off, we'll just ajax to get the data. Javascript side:

```
$.getJSON('urltofilesearch_stores/', {id: locationID}, function (json) {
console.log(json) //this is the data which will be a javascript object
    var html = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var obj     = json[i];
      var id      = obj.ID;
      var name    = obj.CountryAlias;

      html += "<div class="result">id:" + id + " name: " + name + "</div>";
    }
  }).fail(function (err) {
    $('.error').html("error in getting the data");
  }).done(function () {
    $('.element').append(html);
  });
```

And then we have the PHP side. You'll have to `echo` the results for javascript to be able to see them, and make sure **nothing else** gets printed.

```
$sWhere = "WHERE CountryName=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT CountryAlias FROM `t_countrycharges`  "
        . " $sWhere ";
$pacrs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pacrs)){
  $data[]['ID'] = $row['ID'];
  $data[]['CountryAlias'] = $row['CountryAlias'];
}

return json_encode($data);
```